# Does anyone else have trouble syncing to the PAB end to end testnet?

Tags: testnet, pab, plutus-pab

[Plutus PAB Testnode](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/main/plutus-pab/test-node)

git checkout v2021-11-05

Following the instructions on the readme file leads me to a testnet node that is stuck due to a corrupt block error.

```
[relay2:cardano.node.ChainDB:Error:34] [2021-11-18 03:05:39.99 UTC] Invalid block 2fbd8c97cb0643a879564f6fe42c4710486b636c1876a0c454ae8ea202c87d26 at slot 41763999: ExtValidationErrorLedger (HardForkLedgerErrorFromEra S (S (S (S (Z (WrapLedgerErr {unwrapLedgerErr = BBodyError (BlockTransitionError [ShelleyInAlonzoPredFail (LedgersFailure (LedgerFailure (UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (UtxosFailure (ValidationTagMismatch (IsValid True) (FailedUnexpectedly [PlutusFailure "\nThe 2 arg plutus script (PlutusScript PlutusV1 ScriptHash \"8fd8fe8fce219f0ac0f71aa5afd3c98d4ff8c0ccea1c5882852b7914\") fails.\nCekError An error has occurred:  User error:\nThe budget was overspent. Final negative state: ({ cpu: -35982 | mem: 0 })\nThe redeemer is: List []\nThe context is:\nPurpose: Minting 8fd8fe8fce219f0ac0f71aa5afd3c98d4ff8c0ccea1c5882852b7914\nTxInfo:\n  TxId: ecee1d36dc6f4df7e731deba70e14aa51fade20b01aca8089667fc76ba388ba9\n  Inputs: [ c8f1f0677ee4652498bea5eeb5ecbdce9870e065200b6d00333ee6801a315e46!0 -> - Value (Map [(,Map [(\"\",5000000)])]) addressed to\n                                                                                    PubKeyCredential: ef41e0822f758a0fb7507561047f233d4de9a7003e3ce5d551147ced (StakingHash PubKeyCredential: 43ca32d42d6ef66305c91466c15aa65893acb373865c0a75a33f7e2d) ]\n  Outputs: [ - Value (Map [(,Map [(\"\",2581996)])]) addressed to\n               PubKeyCredential: ef41e0822f758a0fb7507561047f233d4de9a7003e3ce5d551147ced (StakingHash PubKeyCredential: 43ca32d42d6ef66305c91466c15aa65893acb373865c0a75a33f7e2d)\n           , - Value (Map [(,Map [(\"\",2000000)]),(8fd8fe8fce219f0ac0f71aa5afd3c98d4ff8c0ccea1c5882852b7914,Map [(\"abc\",1)])]) addressed to\n               ScriptCredential: 8fd8fe8fce219f0ac0f71aa5afd3c98d4ff8c0ccea1c5882852b7914 (no staking credential) ]\n  Fee: Value (Map [(,Map [(\"\",418004)])])\n  Value minted: Value (Map [(8fd8fe8fce219f0ac0f71aa5afd3c98d4ff8c0ccea1c5882852b7914,Map [(\"abc\",1)])])\n  DCerts: []\n  Wdrl: []\n  Valid range: (-\8734 , +\8734)\n  Signatories: []\n  Datums: []\n" "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"]))))))))])}))))))
[relay2:cardano.node.ChainDB:Info:34] [2021-11-18 03:05:39.99 UTC] Valid candidate c7cd93c41b710ae068c793c441a857d540770cceabf20f57ef7f0e01af2819d6 at slot 41763935
```

I sync the testnet then it almost gets done before being stuck.

Has anyone seen this type of error?

There was point when I could sync the entire chain then something created an invalid block.

Comment: Mine is also stuck at 87%

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me.
I solved it by cleaning up the databases and restarting the process.

Comment: I completely deleted the db and resynced and continued to get this issue. I will try again and see what happens.